# Is it possible to create a material ui theme using css?

Tags: css, reactjs, themes, material-ui, css-variables

Using material-ui for react, theming is possible using JSS.
eg.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {      
      main: 'red',
      light: 'pink'
      ...
```

Is it possible to set the color variations using css?
eg.

```
.SomeSelectorForAllClasses {
   --primary:'red';
   --primary-light:'pink'
...
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about swithing between themes?

Comment: For te sake of argument, yes. but I want the new theme to be completely defined in css.

Comment: Not by CSS but using SASS just like material Ui did

Comment: can you provide an example?